# how to implements Multi_threading with connection pooling

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

i have Calc Runner class .in this class 4 methods executing based no number of companies means like this.

```
     for(long companyId : companies){
method1();
method2();
method3();
method4();
}
```

In this methods connections getting from DBStatic util class.Like this
`

```
 try {
            synchronized (LOCK_OBJCT) {
                if (_conn == null || _conn.isClosed()) {
                    Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
                    logger.debug("Connecting to: " + DB_URL + "; as: " + DB_USERID);
                    _conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USERID, DB_PASSWORD); 
                    _conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                } 
                else {
                    logger.debug("Connected to: " + DB_URL + "; as: " + DB_USERID);
                }
            }
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ce) {
            logger.error("Error when obtaining JDBC driver.Exiting...", ce);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Error when obtaining insight db conn: " + DB_URL + "; as: " + DB_USERID + " Exiting..." , e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return _conn;
    }`
```

I we implemented multi threading  with ExcutiveService with 4 thread pool. all methods are executed in thread.
know what is problem with out connection pooling multi threading is not works properly   .how to implements JDBC program for connection pooling for this multi threading

Comment: I you are actually using `java-ee` then the server manages all this for you - it just needs some configuration. No need to reinvent this particular wheel

Answer (score 0):

You should create pooled connection and specify your connection limit. Then you can achieve connection pooling

```
PooledConnectionDataSource ds = new PooledConnectionDataSource();
ds.setDescription("Oracle Data Source");
// Refer to a previously registered pooled data source to access
// a ConnectionPoolDataSource object
ds.setDataSourceName("jdbc/ConnectOracle");
// The pool manager will be initiated with 5 physical connections
ds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
// The pool maintenance thread will make sure that there are 5
// physical connections available
ds.setMinPoolSize(5);
// The pool maintenance thread will check that there are no more
// than 10 physical connections available
ds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
// The pool maintenance thread will wake up and check the pool
// every 20 seconds
ds.setPropertyCycle(20);
// The pool maintenance thread will remove physical connections
// that are inactive for more than 300 seconds
ds.setMaxIdleTime(300);
// Set tracing off since we choose not to see output listing
// of activities on a connection
ds.setTracing(false);
```

Comment: In multi threading environment while close the connection we getting the exception like connect is already closed.we implemented with Jdbc3PoolingDataSource